# Opc.Da.Browse children?

Tags: c#, vb.net, opc

I have this listing to browse the root elements of my Opc.Da server:

```
Dim clone As Opc.Da.Server = m_server 
Dim id As New Opc.ItemIdentifier
Dim filters As New Opc.Da.BrowseFilters
filters.BrowseFilter = Opc.Da.browseFilter.all
Dim pos As Opc.Da.BrowsePosition
Dim elements() As Opc.Da.BrowseElement = clone.Browse(id, filters, pos)
```

But how do I browse the children of each element?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done any vb, but typically there is a method to 'ChangeBrowsePosition' or a 'MoveUp' or 'MoveDown' to go from one node to another. Once in the new node, get the elements of that node.